# Update an Array[JSON] for a POST request in api/v1 of a ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, post

I'm leraning Ruby and I'm trying to create an API to update all the players with a single POST request.
I have to update all the players which have the "ids" on the request.
The post request is given in Array[JSON] form, so I have to compare all the ids for every JSON with the players in the database and I have to update those who have the id specified.
Here the code of the post request:

```
{ 
"players": [
    {
      "player_id": 1,
      "shirt_number": "25",
      "speed": "47",
      "agility": "80",
      "shot": "62",
      "step": "24",
      "technique": "70",
      "contrasts": "59",
      "resistance": "65",
      "parades": "25",
      "aggressiveness": "60",
      "coldness": "50"
    },
    {
      "player_id": 2,
      "shirt_number": "11",
      "speed": “52",
      "agility": “78",
      "shot": “65",
      "step": “23",
      "technique": “60",
      "contrasts": “19",
      "resistance": “44",
      "parades": "25",
      "aggressiveness": "60",
      "coldness": "50"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here there is the code and the parameters:

```
desc 'Update a team'
   params do
      requires :players, type: Array[JSON] do
         requires :id, type: Integer, desc: "Player ID"
         requires :shirt_number, type: String, desc: "Shirt Number"
         requires :speed, type: String, desc: "Speed"
         requires :agility, type: String, desc: "Agility"
         requires :shot, type: String, desc: "Shot"
         requires :step, type: String, desc: "Step"
         requires :technique, type: String, desc: "Technique"
         requires :constrasts, type: String, desc: "Constrasts"
         requires :resistance, type: String, desc: "Resistance"
         requires :parades, type: String, desc: "Parades"
         requires :aggressiveness, type: String, desc: "Aggressiveness"
         requires :coldness, type: String, desc: "Coldness"
     end
  end

post 'update_team' do
  params[:players].each do |player|
  p = Player.find_by(id: params[:id])
  p.update(player)
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work! I didn't find anything about that. Someone can help me? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p = Player.find_by(id: params[:id])` -> From what you've posted, there isn't an `id` parameter and if there was, that would be referencing the same parameter each time through your loop. I think what you want is `p = Player.find_by(id: player['player_id'])`

Also keep in mind that `Player.find_by(id: some_value)` is looking at the database ID, which I imagine might be different from the `player_id`. If this is the case, then `player_id` should probably be a different column in your players table and you would instead do `.find_by(player_id: player['player_id'])`

Additionally, if you are just updating the record in place, you should use `update!`